# Replacing values at a particular offset

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I managed to read values from a binary file between two particular offset values, now I'm stuck. Now I need to replace all values between two particular offsets.

Comment: If the number of bytes between old and new is the same then overwrite just those bytes. If number of bytes is different then you must overwrite everything to the end of file (and set the new end of file if new file is shorter).

Answer (score 0):

If file is not *that long*, you can try *Linq*:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  string fileName = ...

  int offset1 = ...;
  int offset2 = ...;
  byte[] toInsert = ...

  byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); 

  File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data
    .Take(offset1)               // bytes in 0..offset1 range
    .Concat(toInsert)            // bytes to insert
    .Concat(data.Skip(offset2))  // bytes in offset2..eof range
    .ToArray());
```